# error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] *.AuthRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, repository, dagger-hilt

I tried to create a registration using MVVM + Repository pattern with DI, and I used @ViewModelInject and everything was OK, but now @ViewModelInject is deprecated and I changed @ViewModelInject to @HiltViewModel + @Inject constructor() and faced with the `error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] *.AuthRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.` I tried to add a @Provides annotation for the register function in the interface but faced with another error

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

AuthViewModel

```
    @HiltViewModel
    class AuthViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val repository: AuthRepository,
        private val applicationContext: Context,
        private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main
    ) : ViewModel() {
private val _registerStatus = MutableLiveData<Event<Resource<AuthResult>>>()
    val registerStatus: LiveData<Event<Resource<AuthResult>>> = _registerStatus

    private val _loginStatus = MutableLiveData<Event<Resource<AuthResult>>>()
    val loginStatus: LiveData<Event<Resource<AuthResult>>> = _loginStatus

    fun login(email: String, password: String) {
        if(email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            val error = applicationContext.getString(R.string.error_input_empty)
            _loginStatus.postValue(Event(Resource.Error(error)))
        } else {
            _loginStatus.postValue(Event(Resource.Loading()))
            viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
                val result = repository.login(email, password)
                _loginStatus.postValue(Event(result))
            }
        }
    }

    fun register(email: String, username: String, password: String, repeatedPassword: String) {
        val error = if(email.isEmpty() || username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            applicationContext.getString(R.string.error_input_empty)
        } else if(password != repeatedPassword) {
            applicationContext.getString(R.string.error_incorrectly_repeated_password)
        } else if(username.length < MIN_USERNAME_LENGTH) {
            applicationContext.getString(R.string.error_username_too_short, MIN_USERNAME_LENGTH)
        } else if(username.length > MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH) {
            applicationContext.getString(R.string.error_username_too_long, MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH)
        } else if(password.length < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH) {
            applicationContext.getString(R.string.error_password_too_short, MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
        } else if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            applicationContext.getString(R.string.error_not_a_valid_email)
        } else null

        error?.let {
            _registerStatus.postValue(Event(Resource.Error(it)))
            return
        }
        _registerStatus.postValue(Event(Resource.Loading()))
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
            val result = repository.register(email, username, password)
            _registerStatus.postValue(Event(result))
        }
    }
}
```

AppModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideMainDispatcher() = Dispatchers.Main as CoroutineDispatcher

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApplicationContext(@ApplicationContext context: Context) = context

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideGlideInstance(@ApplicationContext context: Context) =
        Glide.with(context).setDefaultRequestOptions(
            RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
        )
}
```

AuthModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object AuthModule {

    @ActivityScoped
    @Provides
    fun provideAuthRepository() = DefaultAuthRepository() as AuthRepository

}
```

AuthRepository

```
interface AuthRepository {

    suspend fun register(email: String, username: String, password: String): Resource<AuthResult>

    suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): Resource<AuthResult>
}
```

DefaultAuthRepository

```
class DefaultAuthRepository : AuthRepository {

    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val users = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users")


    override suspend fun register(
        email: String,
        username: String,
        password: String
    ): Resource<AuthResult> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            safeCall {
                val result = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
                val uid = result.user?.uid!!
                val user = User(uid, username)
                users.document(uid).set(user).await()
                Resource.Success(result)
            }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): Resource<AuthResult> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

//Dagger - Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31.2-alpha'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.31.2-alpha'
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha03'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj5U6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With new hilt version lots of stuff has been changed.
You also have to upgrade your hilt android, hilt compiler and hilt gradle plugin to:2.31-alpha
I made mock sample exactly the way you did i had same issue, after going through hilt's docs i found new way to inject dependencies to viewModels, you have to make separate module for dependencies which are going to inject in the viewModel with special component called ViewModelComponent:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class) // this is new
object RepositoryModule{

    @Provides
    @ViewModelScoped // this is new
    fun providesRepo(): ReposiotryIMPL { // this is just fake repository
        return ReposiotryIMPL()
    }

}
```

here is what docs says about ViewModelComponent and ViewModelScoped

All Hilt View Models are provided by the ViewModelComponent which follows the same lifecycle as a ViewModel, i.e. it survives configuration changes. To scope a dependency to a ViewModel use the @ViewModelScoped annotation.

A @ViewModelScoped type will make it so that a single instance of the scoped type is provided across all dependencies injected into the Hilt View Model.
link: https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html

then your viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class RepoViewModel @Inject constructor(
    application: Application,
    private val reposiotryIMPL: ReposiotryIMPL
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {}
```

﻿

Answer (score 1):

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
abstract class AuthModule{

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindAuthRepository(impl: DefaultAuthRepository): AuthRepository
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have the same error. https://github.com/YaroslavSulyma/TripApp/tree/YaroslavSulyma